# Best practice for Zend Translate with images?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization

I'm using Zend_Translate for a relatively small, bi-lingual site, and was wondering how best to handle language-specific images.

Quick example of how I'm using it:

Bootstrap.php

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate('array',
                                APPLICATION_PATH . '/../languages/',
                                null,
                                array('scan'    => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME,
                                      'locale'  => $locale->getLanguage())
                               );
```

index.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->translate('home.intro'); ?>
```

message.en.php

```
return array(
    'home.intro'    => 'Welcome!'
);
```

Is it normally best to place the whole img tag into the translation array, ready to echo out with $this->translate from the view:

```
'home.banner' => '<img src="/images/en/banner.png" alt="Welcome" />'
```

or to just have the alt value:

```
'home.banner.alt' => 'Welcome'
```

and then in the view (if we pre-set a 'lang' property):

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $lang; ?>/banner.png"
    alt="<?php echo $this->translate('home.banner.alt'); ?>" />
```

Or is there a better "Zend" way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the better way :

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $lang; ?>/banner.png"
    alt="<?php echo $this->translate('home.banner.alt'); ?>" />
```

but you could use csv file than php array for translation